# What to change/add to an Intel install to boot on an AMD PC?

Tags: intel, amd-processor, amd-ryzen

Yesterday I got a new laptop with an AMD processor, as opposed to the intel computer I had before. I wanted to just switch the 1tb drive from my old computer into my new one so that I wouldn't have to transfer anything. Windows booted fine, but when I try to boot into Ubuntu it just fails.

it initially says "DRM: failed to create kernel channel, -22"

then it moves onto a huge wall of scrolling text that I'm not going to try to copy down. 
I did some quick google searching on that code, but most people who have it seem to have intel PCs, so I'm not sure if those fixes will work for my situation.

I tried plugging in my bootable USB to reinstall Ubuntu, but it gave me an error (that I forgot to copy down) saying that proceeding would be at my own risk, and that it was possible that the computer wouldn't boot properly once I did so.

I put the disk in my old computer and copied all of my documents to an external drive (it boots fine in the old computer still), and I was planning on reinstalling fresh and starting over. 
But before I do that, are there any common problems when going from Intel to AMD on Ubuntu? I know drivers don't exactly work the same way as they do on Windows, but is there maybe a package I need to install before it'll work properly on AMD?

Again, I tried searching for this, but anything that I searched with 'AMD' brought back the result for Ubuntu 20.04 with amd64. I don't know what that means, but I do know that's the .iso I used to install Ubuntu originally and obviously it's not working on AMD.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Many boards with AMD CPUs are too new, and will not work with Ubuntu 20.04. I doubt it has anything to do with the add/change, as the title implies. The problem is going from old to new, rather then from Intel to AMD.

Comment: Ubuntu has drivers for Intel and AMD as long as they are before the Ubuntu version.  20.04 will have newer drivers than 18.04.  amd64 is just what they call 64bit versions, something old that never got changed.  Most people wait about 6 months or more from when new computer hardware comes out to install Linux.